# Pointer Lock API movementX value is slowed down when developer console is open

Tags: javascript, html

#### Update

I noticed then when I open the console and do a performance profile it works fast as usual, but when I stop the performance profile (not the dev console it's still open), it slows down again.

Here's some related link where movementX might be unreliable [Mouse event's movementX and movementY showing different values in two machines, both with same device pixel ratio. How come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294502/mouse-events-movementx-and-movementy-showing-different-values-in-two-machines)

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wbhsP/ and observe the movementX value is really small compared to dev console open or not, while moving the mouse left and right.

```
function app(el) {
  bind_pointer(el)({
  onMove(xy) {
  console.log(xy)
  }
  })
  console.log('ok')
}


app(document.getElementById('app')!)


function bind_pointer($element: HTMLElement) {
  return (hooks: PointerHooks) => {

    let { onPointerUnlock, onPointerLock, onClick, onDown, onUp } = hooks

    const onMove = (e: MouseEvent) => hooks.onMove([e.movementX, e.movementY])

    const test_pointer_lock = (on_pointer_lock: () => void, on_no_lock?: () => void) => {
      return () => {
        if (document.pointerLockElement === $element) {
          on_pointer_lock()
        } else {
          on_no_lock?.()
        }
      }
    } 

    let just_exited = false
    document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', test_pointer_lock(() => {
      onPointerLock()
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove, false)
    }, () => {
      onPointerUnlock()
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMove, false)
      just_exited = true
      setTimeout(() => {
        just_exited = false
      }, 1600)
    }))


    $element.addEventListener('click', test_pointer_lock(onClick, () => {
      if (!just_exited) {
        $element.requestPointerLock()
      }
    }))

    $element.addEventListener('mousedown', test_pointer_lock(onDown))
    $element.addEventListener('mouseup', test_pointer_lock(onUp))
  }
}
```

I can't really produce a reproducable because Pointer Lock API doesn't work in examples,

But if you run this kind of code in a real setting, it works like
real small values like at most 20 for movementX when developer console is open

but nice big numbers up to 100 for movementX when developer console is not open.

So I don't understand why that happens. You might want to log the output on the webpage so it is visible when console is not open.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Pointer Lock API doesn't work in examples? Can't you make a codepen or similar? And which browser are you using?

Comment: Bro, just trust me I tried. It's every browser.

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wbhsP/

Comment: The method is called `requestPointerLock`, not `webkitRequestPointerLock`. Also, JSFiddle doesn’t seem to allow pointer lock, so your example does not work, did you try it? Anyway, I rewrote it as a codepen here: https://codepen.io/Latcarf/pen/QWovdxr?editors=1010 and I can’t see any difference at all whether the devtools are open or not (with Chrome on Linux).

Comment: I pulled off that example from internet, and your example also have the same issue i described. I am running Chrome on Windows 10, also Edge browser behaves the same way. Why is this happening to me, please god help.

Comment: Maybe you have some browser extension that slows down the devtools?

Comment: No I have no extensions installed on Edge, default browser, it also has the same issue.